# Worksheet_Activate event handler to activate sheet when clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, named "Salary Sheet" and "ESI_Punjab".
In Salary Sheet I have columns
Column A: emp_Code like 1, 2, 3, ...
Column J: State Name like Punjab, Haryana, Maharashtra, ...

I want, if I activate Sheet "ESI Punjab" then all emp_code with State Name Punjab should be pasted in sheet "ESI Punjab" in column A below heading "emp_code" which is also in sheet "ESI Punjab".

When I click on Sheet "ESI_Punjab" this sheet should be activated but Sheet "Salary Sheet is activated.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim EP As Worksheet, ss As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set EP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ESI_Punjab")
Set ss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Salary Sheet")

EP.Range("a3").RowHeight = 48

EP.Range("a1").ColumnWidth = 11.14
EP.Range("b1").ColumnWidth = 14.86
EP.Range("c1").ColumnWidth = 24
EP.Range("d1").ColumnWidth = 20.86
EP.Range("e1").ColumnWidth = 16
EP.Range("f1").ColumnWidth = 39.43
EP.Range("g1").ColumnWidth = 13.57

EP.Range("a3").Value = "Employee Code"
EP.Range("a3").WrapText = True
EP.Range("b3").Value = "IP Number"
EP.Range("c3").Value = "IP Name"
EP.Range("d3").Value = "No of Days for which wages paid/payable during the month"
EP.Range("e3").Value = "Total Monthly Wages"
EP.Range("f3").Value = "Reason Code for Zero workings days(numeric only; provide 0 for all 
other reasons- Click on the link for reference)"
EP.Range("g3").Value = "Last Working Day"
EP.Range("b3:g3").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 255)
EP.Range("b3:g3").Font.Bold = True
EP.Range("b3:g3").WrapText = True

ss.Activate
For i = 5 To ss.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ss.Cells(i, 10).Value = "Punjab" Then
        ss.Cells(i, 10).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Copy EP.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Set ss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Salary Sheet")` and later `ss.Activate` so why is what you're seeing unexpected?

Comment: You don't need to `Select` cell in order to copy, `ss.Cells(i, 10).Select: ActiveCell.Off(0, -9) ....` can instead change to `ss.Cells(i, 10).Offset(0, -9).Copy EP.Range ....`. Or if you simply just want the value, `EP.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ss.Cells(i, 10).Offset(0, -9).Value` should work too